# Handle DI errors in Owin/Katana and Autofac

Tags: .net, error-handling, owin, autofac, katana

I've got a WebApi2 Owin self-host app using Autofac DI integration. Recently I spent some time troubleshooting an issue with middleware constructor injection without any hints or any useful exception details and wondering how I should improve the code below to provide error details in all cases. I'm using the [recommended approach for global error handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling) but looks like it doesn't handle everything. Consider the following snippets:

Middleware:

```
public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    IClaimAuthorizationProvider claimProvider;

    public ClientCertificateAuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions options, IClaimAuthorizationProvider claimProvider)
        : base(next, options)
    {
        this.claimProvider = claimProvider;
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler(claimProvider);
    }
}
```

App builder, DI configuration

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
// error handling
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger());
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

// DI registrations
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterType<ClaimAuthorizationProvider>().As<IClaimAuthorizationProvider>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
// missing registration causing the error
//builder.RegisterInstance(new ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions());
builder.RegisterType<ClientCertificateAuthenticationMiddleware>().InstancePerRequest();    
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// integrate Autofac into Owin pipeline
appBuilder.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```

With this configuration I was getting the following response, without `IExceptionHandler` and `IExceptionLogger` being hit:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 07:55:00 GMT

The cause of the problem was quite trivial - missing dependency registration (the one commented out), but without any error details it wasn't easy to nail it down, so **My question is: How do I configure the app so that ALL exceptions, absolutely Everything that is unhandled gets logged with details?** (Something I was expecting from `IExceptionHandler`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the global (webapi) error handler and error logger are intercepting exceptions in the Webapi tier/middleware. For all the other middlewares, like the custom authentication above, you have to take care of error handling/logging.

Comment: Thanks @bandreas! You're right, pushing a simple ExceptionLoggingMiddleware on top of the app helped.